# Gcloud-VPN with multiple IP-range is not connected to SonicWall

Tags: vpn, gcloud

I'm using Gcloud VPN beta version with Windows server 2008 R2 VM.

When I try to connect the VPN to our company's local domain through SonicWall, it went successfully when only one IP range was used.

When I add the second IP range to the tunnel, Google Cloud console shows no error, but the VM can only connect to one IP range, and the connection switched from one IP range to the other from time to time with no pattern at all.

Does anyone have an idea about what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue could be with the SonicWall.
Have you tried to reproduce the issue without the firewall?
You could take snapshots of the disk and make it the boot disk on new instances and try it out. I haven't seen this issue before but it would be a good way to see where the issue lies.
Let me know what happens.

Thank you